# Return a generic subtype with an upper bound in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following Swift functions:

```
private func authorizedMutableURLRequest(#ref: String) -> Result<NSMutableURLRequest> {
    ...
}
public func fetch(#ref: String) -> Result<NSURLRequest> {
    switch authorizedMutableURLRequest(ref: ref) {
    case .Success(let mutableURLRequestBox):
        return .Success(JiveBox(mutableURLRequestBox.value))
    case .Failure(let error):
        return .Failure(error)
    }
}
```

There must be a better way to write `fetch`. If this was Java, I'd write:

```
public Result<? extends NSURLRequest> fetch(String ref) {
    return authorizedMutableURLRequest(ref);
}
private Result<NSMutableURLRequest> authorizedMutableURLRequest(String ref) {
    ...
}
```

And everything would work correctly. Is there a way to return an unspecified type with an upper bound in Swift like there is in Java?